# WPF Combobox binding to DataTable not working

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

ComboBox is defined as

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbCallSource" />
```

At form load I run this code (I checked that dtSources datatable ends up with proper contents in debugger):

```
//Init Source List
        dtSources = new DataTable();
        dtSources.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Key", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
        dtSources.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Caption", Type.GetType("System.String")));
        dtSources.Rows.Add(new object[] { -1, Utility.GetStringByKey("string1") }); ;
        dtSources.Rows.Add(new object[] { 0, Utility.GetStringByKey("string2") }); ;
        dtSources.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, Utility.GetStringByKey("string3") }); ;
        dtSources.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, Utility.GetStringByKey("string4") }); ;
        dtSources.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, Utility.GetStringByKey("string5") }); ;
        dtSources.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, Utility.GetStringByKey("string6") }); ;

        //Attempt 1
        cmbCallSource.DataContext = dtSources.DefaultView;
        cmbCallSource.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
        cmbCallSource.DisplayMemberPath = "Caption";

        //Attempt 2
        //Binding myBinding = new Binding("Name");
        //myBinding.Source = dtSources; // data source from your example

        //cmbCallSource.DisplayMemberPath = "Caption";
        //cmbCallSource.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
        //cmbCallSource.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

I tried both ways (second one is commented out). Combobox ends up empty either way. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Itemsource property, not the DataContext

```
cmbCallSource.ItemsSource = dtSources.DefaultView;
```